# Expected reference, found enum `Result` on cloned() method

Tags: rust, error-handling, closures

On function `result_with_list()` I'm trying to apply `cloned()` or `copied()` before calling `collect()`

I get compile time error saying `expected reference, found enum Result` on `cloned()` function and `method cannot be called on` `Copied<Map<std::vec::IntoIter<i32>, [closure@exercises/standard_library_types/iterators3.rs:43:29: 43:32]>>` `due to unsatisfied trait bounds` on `collect()` method

I have a custom Error returned in a Result from the `divide()` function and may be that is causing an issue ? May be the function signature `Result<i32,DivisionError>` could be modified to another signature ?

```
 #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
    pub enum DivisionError {
        NotDivisible(NotDivisibleError),
        DivideByZero,
    }

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct NotDivisibleError {
    dividend: i32,
    divisor: i32,
}

use DivisionError::{DivideByZero,NotDivisible}; 
use std::iter::Iterator;

// Calculate `a` divided by `b` if `a` is evenly divisible by `b`.
// Otherwise, return a suitable error.
pub fn divide(a: i32, b: i32) -> Result<i32, DivisionError> {
    if b==0 {
        Err(DivideByZero)
    }
    else if a%b!=0 {
        Err(NotDivisible(NotDivisibleError {dividend: a,divisor: b}))
    }
    else { Ok(a/b) }
   
}

// Complete the function and return a value of the correct type so the test passes.
// Desired output: Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])
fn result_with_list() -> Result<i32,DivisionError> {
    let numbers = vec![27, 297, 38502, 81];
    numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).copied().collect()
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cloned()` or `copied()` are for converting references (`&i32`) into values (`i32`). They are often relevant to iterating over numbers, but not in your situation because *there are no references involved* — `numbers.into_iter()` consumes the `Vec` and returns its elements.

After removing `.copied()`, the next error is:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `i32` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `i32`
```

This error is because you have declared your function to return `Result<i32, DivisionError>` — a *single* number in the `Result`. But you want it to return four numbers, so you'll need to change the return type. This will compile:

```rust
fn result_with_list() -> Result<Vec<i32>, DivisionError> {
    let numbers = vec![27, 297, 38502, 81];
    numbers.into_iter().map(|n| divide(n, 27)).collect()
}
```

Note: in serious Rust programs, functions whose main work is iterating should usually *return the iterator* rather than collecting it into a specific collection type. In this case, since the problem statement is “Desired output: `Ok([1, 11, 1426, 3])`”, that is what you want to do. Just note that it's not ideal (because it may mean creating a collection that will then be thrown out after the *next* step of the bigger problem takes it as input).

Comment: I completely missed that. It works now :) And yes this was exercise. Will keep that in mind for prod code.